# Unable to download Azure DevOps test result attachments using REST API in Groovy Unable to determine the current character

Tags: groovy, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to download test result file attachments to a folder on my hard drive.

When I run the call using talend it returns the file (png) image file in the body

The GET call I'm sending is:
https://dev.azure.com/myorg/Sandbox/_apis/test/Runs/1347512/Results/100001/attachments/1520956?api-version=6.0-preview.1

Returns the image in the body

[image]

When I run this call in Groovy I use the following method in the main class to call the testManagementService class

```
    def project = 'myproject'
    def runId = '1514421'
    def resultId = '100001'
    def attachId = '1520956'
    def downloadFiles = testManagementService.downloadResAttachments(project, runId, resultId, attachId)
```

Here's the downloadResAttachments method in the testManagementService class

```
public def downloadResAttachments(project, runId, resultId, attachId) {
    def collection = "zionseto"
    def eproject = URLEncoder.encode(project, 'utf-8')
    eproject = eproject.replace('+', '%20')
    
    def result = genericRestClient.get(
        contentType: ContentType.JSON,
        //requestContentType: ContentType.JSON,
        uri: "${genericRestClient.getTfsUrl()}/${collection}/${project}/_apis/test/Runs/${runId}/Results/${resultId}/attachments/${attachId}?",
        
        headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/json'],
        query: ['api-version':'6.0-preview.1', 'expand': 'all']
        )

    return result;

}
```

When I run this code it returns the following error:

*Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
The current character read is '?' with an int value of 65533
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
?PNG
^
at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValueInternal(JsonParserCharArray.java:202)
at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValue(JsonParserCharArray.java:153)
at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeFromChars(JsonParserCharArray.java:43)
at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.parse(JsonParserCharArray.java:380)
at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.BaseJsonParser.parse(BaseJsonParser.java:133)
at groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(JsonSlurper.java:218)
at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseJSON(ParserRegistry.java:280)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1260)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodClosure(MetaClassImpl.java:1040)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1134)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:560)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:489)*

I'm guessing I need to modify the code to handle the file attachment download and save the file to disk?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show how you are creating genericRestClient and what library/version you are using for it.

Comment: Thanks @daggett I figured out the issue.  I needed to change the Content-Type of 'application/json' to contentType: 'application/octet-stream'

Answer (score 0):

In the testManagementService I had to change Content-Type to 'application/octet-stream'

```
    def result = genericRestClient.get(
    **contentType: 'application/octet-stream',**
    uri: "${genericRestClient.getTfsUrl()}/${collection}/${project}/_apis/test/Runs/${runId}/Results/${resultId}/attachments/${attachId}?",
    
    headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'],
    query: ['api-version':'6.0-preview.1', 'expand': 'all']
```